# Segfault when adding QwtPlot to the code

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qwt

I try to use QwtPlot, but when i add this line to my `MainWindow.cpp`

```
QwtPlot *plot = new QwtPlot(QwtText("Demo"), this);
```

the application compile and link without errors, but when I try to run it I get

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff514227c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
```

without any backtrace. My `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qwt
CONFIG += qwt
LIBS += -lqwt
```

I'm using Qwt 6.0.2, Qt Creator 2.7.0 and have Qt 4.8.4 and 5.0.2 installed.

The error also occours when I create a "Qt Gui Application" (without .ui file) and just this code:

qwt-test.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qwt-test
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qwt
CONFIG += qwt
LIBS += -lqwt

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.hpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "main";
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.hpp

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
// MainWindow.cpp
#include "MainWindow.hpp"

#include <qwt_plot.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QwtPlot *plot = new QwtPlot(QwtText("Demo"), this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: change this QwtText("Demo") to "Demo"

Comment: Thats what I had first, gives me a `error: no matching function for call to 'QwtPlot::QwtPlot(const char [5], MainWindow* const)'`. Also this part comes from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763596/segfault-when-adding-qwt-plot-to-layout)

Comment: Try to run in debug mode and find where is the Access violation  is happening. I think you have maid mistake some where else in the program.

Comment: gdb failed directly after `start`. I made a new project and just copied the above code into the constructor of the main window and `qDebug() << "main";` directly after `main(..) {`: no changes and no output.

Comment: You didn't give enough information to fix your problem. Please provide the lines before this line. And which IDE you are using ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the question and added everything.

Comment: Add a full backtrace, preferably with debug builds of Qt and qwt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a problem with Qt Creator (or Qwt being incompatible with Qt 5), it recognized qmake as qmake for Qt 4 but it was for Qt 5. Fixing the versions in Options -> Build&Run -> Qt Versions and using Qt 4 for the project fixed the segfault.